# Item-based collaborative filtering

Tags: ruby, clustering

I wrote the following code using Ruby to compute item-based [collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) (using [Jaccard coefficient of similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)).

I would appreciate feedback about any potential issues with the code and tips to make the code better comply with the best practices.

```
require 'json'
require 'set'

def compute_jaccard_coefficients(users_for_activities)
    jaccard_coefficient_hash = {}
    all_activities = Set.new
    users_for_activities.each do |key1, array1|
        users_for_activities.each do |key2, array2|
            if key1 != key2
                all_activities.add key1
                all_activities.add key2
                intersected_users = array1 & array2
                unioned_users = array1 | array2
                if unioned_users.length > 0
                    jaccard_coefficient_hash[[key1, key2]] = intersected_users.length.fdiv(unioned_users.length)
                    else
                    jaccard_coefficient_hash[[key1, key2]] = 0
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return [jaccard_coefficient_hash, all_activities]
end

data = '[
{"user": "1", "activities": ["running", "swimming", "rowing"]},
{"user": "2", "activities": ["tennis", "rowing"]},
{"user": "3", "activities": ["swimming", "running"]},
{"user": "4", "activities": ["tennis", "swimming"]}
]'

parsed_data = JSON.parse(data)

users_for_activities = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}

parsed_data.each do |child|
    child["activities"].each do |activity|
        users_for_activities[activity] << child["user"]
    end
end

all_activities = Set.new
jaccard_coefficient_hash, all_activities = compute_jaccard_coefficients(users_for_activities)

parsed_data.each do |child|
    activities_to_recommend = {}
    child["activities"].each do |user_activity|
        all_activities.each do |generic_activity|
            if user_activity != generic_activity
                if activities_to_recommend.has_key?(generic_activity)
                    if jaccard_coefficient_hash[[user_activity, generic_activity]] > activities_to_recommend[generic_activity]
                        unless child["activities"].include?(generic_activity)
                            activities_to_recommend[generic_activity] = jaccard_coefficient_hash[[user_activity, generic_activity]]
                        end
                    end
                    else
                    unless child["activities"].include?(generic_activity)
                        activities_to_recommend[generic_activity] = jaccard_coefficient_hash[[user_activity, generic_activity]]
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    print "User " + child["user"] + ": "
    print activities_to_recommend.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
    print "\n"
end
```

Output:

> ```
> User 1: [["tennis", 0.3333333333333333]]
> User 2: [["running", 0.3333333333333333], ["swimming", 0.25]]
> User 3: [["rowing", 0.3333333333333333], ["tennis", 0.25]]
> User 4: [["running", 0.6666666666666666], ["rowing", 0.3333333333333333]]
> ```

Comment: Please provide the actual hash passed to the method. The data in your question is a) a JSON string, and b) indexed by user. Unless I'm mistaken, the method operates on the inverse: Users indexed by activity. Sure, we can write our own input, but it shouldn't really be our responsibility. We also won't know if we got it right if we just feed it stuff we make up.

Comment: @Flambino thanks for the suggestions. The json object is a toy example of the kind of input we receive to compute our recommendations. Perhaps I can move the data transformation part into the wrapper code (not shown in this self-contained example) so that this code focuses on the actual technique.

Comment: Actually, never mind. I goofed. I realize now that there was more to the code in the question. For whatever reason, my tablet's browser didn't let me scroll the code :P

Comment: @Flambino that's alright :). The code in its entirety would hopefully make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It appears, that these lines of code are junk you forgot to remove:

   ```
   unless child["activities"].include?(generic_activity)
   ```
2. Instead of accumulating `set`, just use `users_for_activities.keys`.
3. Replace:

   ```
   child["activities"].each do |user_activity|
       all_activities.each do |generic_activity|
           if user_activity != generic_activity
   ```

   with:

   ```
   child["activities"].product(all_activities - child["activities"]) do |user_activity, generic_activity|
   ```

   that saves you two levels of indentation.
4. The same trick here to replace:

   ```
   users_for_activities.each do |key1, array1|
       users_for_activities.each do |key2, array2|
           if key1 != key2
   ```

   with:

   ```
   users_for_activities.to_a.permutation(2) do |(key1, array1), (key2, array2)|
   ```
5. You may use `.empty?` instead of `.length > 0` or this:

   ```
   if 0 == total_users = array1.length + array2.length
       jaccard_coefficient_hash[[key1, key2]] = 0
   else
       jaccard_coefficient_hash[[key1, key2]] = intersected_users.length.fdiv(total_users)
   end
   ```
6. Since recommendations can't be negative, you may get rid of another `if` because of its awful code length by defaulting the result to zero in this way:

   ```
   activities_to_recommend[generic_activity] = [
       activities_to_recommend[generic_activity] || 0,
       jaccard_coefficient_hash[[user_activity, generic_activity]]
   ].max
   ```

   or this:

   ```
   activities_to_recommend = Hash.new 0
   ```
7. By changing loops nesting order we can start using `Array#max` and do a step to get rid of imperativity here, since we stop walk randomly through `activities_to_recommend`:

   ```
   parsed_data.each do |child|
       activities_to_recommend = Hash.new 0
       (users_for_activities.keys - child["activities"]).each do |generic_activity|
           activities_to_recommend[generic_activity] =
               child["activities"].map{ |user_activity|
                   jaccard_coefficient_hash[[user_activity, generic_activity]]
               }.max || 0
       end
       puts "User #{child["user"]}: #{activities_to_recommend.sort_by{ |k,v| -v }}"
   end
   ```
8. *(optional)* But that getting rid of imperativity isn't too nice -- most people won't like this:

   ```
   activities_to_recommend = (users_for_activities.keys - child["activities"]).map do |generic_activity| [
       generic_activity,
       child["activities"].map{ |user_activity|
           jaccard_coefficient_hash[[user_activity, generic_activity]]
       }.max || 0
   ] end
   ```
9. *(optional)* If you try to rewrite `users_for_activities` creation into functional and method-chaining way, you'll get this controversial thing:

   ```
   users_for_activities = parsed_data.flat_map{ |child|
       child["activities"].map{ |activity| [activity, child["user"]] }
   }.group_by(&:first).tap{ |h| h.each{ |k,v| v.map! &:last } }
   ```
10. *(optional)* Hash with array as a key, rather than simple scalar, like an Integer, can have sudden collisions, but since your array items are Strings, you probably can forget about that.

Comment: thanks for the detailed review and explanation about alternate techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Stuff I noticed:

- Use `next` to skip an `each`-iteration instead of wrapping everything in an `if` statement
- No need for `Set`. A hash's keys are already a set, so in your `compute_jaccard_coefficients` method you could just call `all_activties = users_for_activities.keys` and done. From the raw data, you could do `all_activities = parsed_data.map { |user| user['activities'] }.flatten.uniq`
- I'd absolutely avoid returning a tuple from the `compute_jaccard_coefficients` method. As illustrated above, getting all the activities isn't difficult; you can do that anywhere. And the method itself doesn't use the set for anything; creating the set is just something it *also* does, even though it shouldn't be its responsibility. Your code definitely shouldn't rely on a method just randomly doing something
- Since your method is checking combinations of activities, you might as well use `Array#combination`. Give it an argument of `2` and it'll give you an array of pairs activities. Note that it'll also give only *unique* combinations - i.e. you'll get a pair like `["tennis", "swimming"]`, but it'll skip `["swimming", "tennis"]` since that's the same combination.
- Favor methods like `any?` (or better - as Naklion points out in the comments - `empty?`) over checking an array's length with `arr.count > 0`

With the above in mind, the method can be written as

```
def compute_jaccard_coefficients(hash)
  coefficients = hash.keys.combination(2).map do |a, b|
    union = hash[a] | hash[b]
    weight = union.empty? ? 0 : (hash[a] & hash[b]).count / union.count.to_f
    [[a, b], weight]
  end
  Hash[coefficients]
end
```

Note that this implementation also gives you a cleaner result (no duplicate combinations) in fewer iterations.

I'm out of time right now, but I'll take a look at the rest of the code later.

---

Update: It's now "later", and [Naklion has provided a very nice answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55218/14370). Still, I'll give it a go too.

I used `combination` above, whereas Naklion used `permutation`. The latter gives an identical result to the original code (i.e. the coefficients hash will have keys for both tennis/rowing and rowing/tennis). Using `combination` you'll only get *unique* combinations, and thus fewer coefficient calculations, but lookup gets a bit more complex (which I wasn't considering when just looking at the Jaccard method). Still, since Naklion used `permutations`, I'll stick to `combinations`.

One addition, though, is to use `Set` (after all) to create the keys of the Jaccard hash:

```
def compute_jaccard_coefficients(hash)
  coefficients = hash.keys.combination(2).map do |a, b|
    union = hash[a] | hash[b]
    weight = union.empty? ? 0 : (hash[a] & hash[b]).count / union.count.to_f
    [Set[a, b], weight]
  end
  Hash[coefficients]
end
```

This allows us to look up weights without worrying bout the order of the key's elements, since `Set[a, b] == Set[b, a]`.

Naklion provided a nice way (#9 on the list) to transpose the `parsed_data` from user-indexed activities to activity-indexed users, so I'll skip over that.

So starting with this (and the method above)

```
all_activities = users_for_activities.keys
coefficients = compute_jaccard_coefficients(users_for_activities)
```

you can do this

```
parsed_data.each do |user|
  possibles = all_activities - user['activities'] # activities the user doesn't have already
  recommendations = user['activities'].product(possibles).map do |a, b|
    # a is the user's existing activity, b is the recommended activity
    key = Set[a, b]
    [b, coefficients[key]] if coefficients[key] > 0
  end.compact.sort_by(&:last).reverse

  puts "User #{user[:user]}: #{recommendations}"
end
```

Comment: **+1** the `[[a,b],0] ; end ; Hash[...]` style. **-1** `any?` is bad way to check length.

Comment: @Nakilon What's the problem with `any?`? It reads well, and (as far as I know) is functionally equivalent to just checking that the length is greater than zero

Comment: `[].any?` == `[nil].any?` == `[false].any?` == `false`. The proper method is `.empty?`

Comment: @Nakilon Ah, right. Wasn't thinking of nil/false values (since all we have here _should be_ strings). Thanks

Comment: @flambino thanks for the detailed review and comparing the approaches of the two answers.